# A cone in the "boundary" of a convex cone, without topology

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

In a real vector space, I have two **nonempty disjoint** cones $A,B$, such that:

1. $A$ is a convex cone.
2. $A \cup B$ is a convex cone.
3. for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, we have $a+b \in A$.

So you see from (3) that $B$ is in some sense contained in the "boundary" of $A$. But I don't want to assume a topology on the vector space. My question is, has this phenomenon been discussed in any references? Is there a name for it? Are there any relevant tools or implications on $A$ and $B$?

Added: A cone by my definition need not contain $\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 1):

To make things concrete, I guess you're thinking of something like
$A = \big\{(c_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb N} : \lim_n c_n = \infty \big\}$
and $B$ is any cone in $\ell^\infty$.

What relationship do you want $A$ and $B$ to have?

Comment: Ah, that's a nice example. I was mostly visualizing examples in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Unfortunately I don't have a very clear idea what I want, which is why I would love a reference where this phenomenon arises naturally in some context and seeing what is shown about it.

Comment: But I guess an example statement I tentatively had in mind was "if $A = \cap_i \{x : f_i(x) < 0\}$ for linear $f_i$, then $B \subseteq \cup_i \{ x : f_i(x) = 0 \}$.

Comment: I guess your conditions allow $A=B$.

Comment: disjoint, nonempty!